# Not getting the decrypted OpenVPN Username from the Registry the same way that works for getting the decrypted Password

Tags: powershell, encryption, windows-10, registry, add-type

I have a Powershell script that I am successfully using to get the decrypted OpenVPN Password stored in Registry.

This is the script that successfully fetches the stored OpenVPN Password from registry that too as decrypted string:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$keys = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\OpenVPN-GUI\configs"
$items = $keys | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}

foreach ($item in $items)
{
  $encryptedbytes=$item.'auth-data'
  $entropy=$item.'entropy'
  $entropy=$entropy[0..(($entropy.Length)-2)]

  $decryptedbytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect(
    $encryptedBytes,
    $entropy,
    [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)

  Write-Host ([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($decryptedbytes))
}
```

But if I do some modification to this for fetching the decrypted `username` from the same OpenVPN Registry section and using the correct key `username` like below, it doesn't fetch the decrypted Username:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$keys = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\OpenVPN-GUI\configs"
$items = $keys | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}

foreach ($item in $items)
{
  $entropy=$item.'entropy'
  $username=$item.'username'
  $encryptedbytes=$item.'auth-data'
  $entropy=$entropy[0..(($entropy.Length)-2)]
  $username=$username[0..(($username.Length)-2)]

  $decryptedbytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect(
    $encryptedBytes,
    $username,
    [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)

  Write-Host ([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($decryptedbytes))
}
```

Can anyone help out in knowing what am I doing wrong here and fix this ?

Comment: Are you certain it is encrypted?

Comment: @DougMaurer Not sure, but it does look like an encrypted string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the username is stored unencrypted. Just decode it as Unicode. This may change in future versions. For encrypted data, the call to Unprotect() would take $entropy as the second argument, not $username.